# AndAlso not short circuiting in IIF

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone elaborate, why the second one throws InvalidOperationException "Nullable object must have a value" if foo is Nothing? I would expect it to work the same as the first snippet, but obviously I'm missing something:

Snippet 1:

```
If foo IsNot Nothing AndAlso foo.HasValue Then
                            _foo = foo.Value.Days
                        Else
                            _foo = 365
                        End If
```

Does not throw if foo is Nothing (as expected)

Snippet 2:

```
_foo = CInt(IIf(foo IsNot Nothing AndAlso foo.HasValue, foo.Value.Days, 365))
```

Throws InvalidOperationException if foo is Nothing - why?

Comment: To be clear, the AndAlso is shorting properly. as Tim said, it is the IIf that is not shorting. Delete the AndAlso and the IIf still throws an exception. Replace the conditions with FunctionA() AndAlso FunctionB() where FunctionA and FunctionB return booleans and you will see that the AndAlso is not the culprit.

Answer (score 8):

Because the old [`IIf` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) is not the new [`If` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator). The old one does not short-circuit whereas the new one does.

```
_foo = If(foo IsNot Nothing AndAlso foo.HasValue, foo.Value.Days, 365)
```

You also don't need to cast with `If` as opposed to `IIf`.

You could make it more concise with the new [null-conditional-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) `?`:

```
_foo = If(foo?.Days, 365)
```

With 2 parameters the `If`-operator is a null-coalescing, with 3 it's used as a conditonal-operator.